# TableViewer selection changing

Tags: java, block, jface, master-detail, tableviewer

I have a little problem and I'm asking for help.

I have a `TableViewer` in my Master part and a lot of entries updating it very quickly.
My details pages display the selected item infos.
I would like to make this details pages persistent and only be notified when selection is changing.

The problem I'm facing is that when a new item is added to the tableviewer, the selection changes automatically.

EDITING : I have a Handler which update the `TableViewer`, adding a new item at the beginning of a list which is the input of my `TableViewer`.

When the `TableViewer` is `SWT.VIRTUAL` the selection is on the index and when an item is added, the selected row is the same but items have moved.

When `TableViewer` is not `SWT.VIRTUAL` the selection occurs on the object but performances are very low !

Any piece of advice ?
Thank you

```
public void update(Object obj_p) {
    if (obj_p instanceof IMessageEvent) {
        IMessageEvent event = (IMessageEvent) obj_p;
        synchronized (_currentListEvents) {
            _currentListEvents.addFirst(event);
            if (_currentListEvents.size() > _maxEvents) {
                _currentListEvents.removeLast();
            }
        }
    }
    if (null == obj_p) {
        synchronized (_currentListEvents) {
            _currentListEvents.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you add new item to the tableviewer, the selection change event doesn't occur automatically. How do you add this new item?

Comment: I'm adding it in the update() method. The fact is that when my TableViewer is not SWT.VIRTUAL the selection doesn't change.

Comment: Could you please post some code here? Especially the part when you add new items to the TableViewer.

Comment: Now I see, this is really interesting. I would investigate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating TableViewer use SWT.FULL_SELECTION style.

There is a simple runable code. It behaves exactly as you posted, the selection is being changed, but when you use the commented TableViewer constructor, it works for me.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ArrayContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelectionChangedListener;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.LabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.SelectionChangedEvent;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class TestCase {

private static List<String> model = new ArrayList<String>();
private static TableViewer viewer;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

//  viewer = new TableViewer(shell, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.FULL_SELECTION |    SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.VIRTUAL);
    viewer = new TableViewer(shell, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.VIRTUAL);

    viewer.getTable().setHeaderVisible(true);
    viewer.getTable().setLinesVisible(true);
    viewer.setUseHashlookup(true);

    viewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
    viewer.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider());

    model.add("element2");
    model.add("element1");
    model.add("element0");

    viewer.setInput(model);

    viewer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(model.get(1)));

    viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
            System.out.println("selection changed");
        }
    });

    addContent();

    shell.setSize(400, 400);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}

private static void addContent() {
    Display.getCurrent().timerExec(2000, new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            model.add(0, "element" + model.size());
            viewer.refresh();
            addContent();
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: thx but SWT.FULL_SELECTION is to select all the columns at once, by the way my TableViewer was SWT.FULL_SELECTION all the time.

Comment: I know it does, but with this style used, it preserves the selection. Without it, the selection gets always changed as you mentioned.

Comment: It is not preserving the selection when TableViewer is SWT.VIRTUAL

Comment: I ran your example and the selection is not preserved for me even with the commented line

Comment: Windows XP pro service pack 3

Comment: So it must be a problem in OS. I have filled a bug for that https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=396604